# Error using JDBC Sampler: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'phpmyadmin/')

Tags: sql, jdbc, jmeter, performance-testing, database-performance

I am unable to connect http://localhost/phpmyadmin by using jmeter... i have placed mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin in lib folder of jmeter directory...

I am using WAMP Server

> Error: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'phpmyadmin/')

Connection settings are as follows:

- DB URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/phpmyadmin/
- JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
- Username:root
- password:

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but you are surely confusing 2 things:

- **phpmyadmin is a web application**. If your goal is to test that web application, you should be using [HTTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request). You cannot test web application using JDBC sampler.
- If you want to test a database on your My SQL instance using JDBC sampler, **you have to provide a name of valid database** just as an error says. Typically instance of MySQL comes with a bunch of system databases, so you can use one of them, for example:

  ```
  DB URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
  ```

  should work, since MySQL typically comes with [test database pre-installed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/database-use.html). Or you can create your own database and provide its name there.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to load test phpMyAdmin web interface - remove JDBC Request sampler and switch to [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request). Most probably you will also need to add a [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) configured to send the relevant credentials (default username is `root` with blank password, if it doesn't fit you can [reset the password](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-have-lost-my-mysql-root-password-what-can-i-do)). See [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) article for example Test Plan for logging into phpMyAdmin web interface
- If you would like to continue playing with the JDBC Request sampler, the error you are getting states that `phpmyadmin` database is missing, you will need to [create this database](https://www.siteground.co.uk/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_create_database.htm) prior to attempting connecting to it using JMeter